# how to get test result status (how many pass, failures, skip) from maven test

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a jenkins ci job that runs a mvn junit test,

I would like to get the test result status and save it as a environment variable or pass it to other party.

> Tests run: 515, Failures: 12, Errors: 6, Skipped: 8

how do i achieve that?  right now i can only read the result manually from the console.

Comment: you most probably need to create a script which either reads the build log or the surefire report. What's the overall process?

Comment: in jenkins job i will run the mvn install which will trigger the junit test.   but at the end of the job i would like to parse the test status information sentence and pass it over to a email report template

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven [Surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/) report. The results will be available as shown [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/surefire-report.html).